# Multiple value in variable and name parse

Tags: shell, ubuntu, sh

I'm writing code to make some `wget` and get the backup file in some routers.

My first problem is with the variable `RT`.  If I declare only IP on this variable (and add the /config.dat or anything else in `wget` line) this script will work, otherwise it will say that the "directory was not found."

How can I declare it as it is in the script below?

My second question: I want to say that the output file `-O` is the IP with the extension .dat for the 2 first IP and for the third it will not have extension just the IP.

Is it possible to do that as I said?

```
#!/bin/sh
RT="10.0.0.59/config.dat 10.0.0.60/cgi-bin/export_settings.cgi 10.0.0.66/rom-0"
MT="10.0.0.57 10.0.0.58"
L_RT="LOGIN"
P_RT="PASSWORD"

#FUTURE USE WITH TAR
#tmp=$"(mktemp -d)"
#trap -- 'rm -frv -- "$tmp"' EXIT
#cd -- "$tmp"

for bkp_rt in $RT; do
   wget --auth-no-challenge --user=$L_RT --password=P_RT $bkp_rt -O $bkp_rt
done
```

After updating my script.

```
#!/bin/bash
RT="10.0.0.59/config.dat 10.0.0.60/cgi-bin/export_settings.cgi 10.0.0.66/rom-0"
MT="10.0.0.57 10.0.0.58"
L_RT="admin"
P_RT="PASSWORD"
L=MT="backup"

#tmp=$"(mktemp -d)"
#trap -- 'rm -frv -- "$tmp"' EXIT
#cd -- "$tmp"

for bkp_rt in $RT; do

wget --auth-no-challenge --user=$L_RT --password=$P_RT \
"$bkp_rt" \
-O "$bkp_rt"
done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the `$` for `--password=P_RT`.

If you want to use `10.0.0.60/cgi-bin/export_settings.cgi` as a filename, you'll have to make sure the `10.0.0.60` and `10.0.0.60/cgi-bin` directories exist first.

To fetch the URL with wget, you will probably need to specify the scheme:

```
for bkp_rt in $RT; do
   mkdir -p "$(dirname "$bkp_rt")"
   wget --auth-no-challenge --user="$L_RT" --password="$P_RT" "$bkp_rt" \
        -O "$bkp_rt"
done
```

Comment: I did the changes that you proposed, This is the output when I execute the script `yamash@PITCAIRN:~/scripts$ ./rt_backup.sh
10.0.0.59/config.dat: File or directory not found
10.0.0.60/cgi-bin/export_settings.cgi: File or directory not found
10.0.0.66/rom-0: File or directory not found`

Comment: I think you need to be clear on the URL you're passing to wget. Is your RT string correct?

Comment: Sorry I'm a begginer, so I did not understand what you mean, I will edit my main post with how the script is right now.

Comment: What happens if you execute this from a shell prompt: `wget --auth-no-challenge --user=admin --password=28244886 10.0.0.60/cgi-bin/export_settings.cgi`

Comment: It download the file successfully 2014-05-06 12:55:28 (256 KB/s) - “export_settings.cgi” salvo [4616]

Comment: It looks like you're just missing the `mkdir` command that I show.